# Why is MS Access treating my table field name as a parameter in WHERE clause?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a parameter query that prompts the user for values (included in brackets.)  When I run the query, I am also prompted with the table field name (which is in parenthesis.)

```
example (Where (degree.degree) = [Desired degree level]
```

I am prompted for both `degree.degree` and `Desired degree level.`

I shouldn't be prompted for the table field name.  Anyone had this problem?  I have found nothing in my searches.

Answer (score 2):

Usually those "surprise parameters" are caused by a spelling error somewhere in the query.  If you've already confirmed those spellings are correct, I'm not sure what's going on, but I would try the query this way:

```sql
SELECT d.*
FROM degree AS d
WHERE d.degree = [Desired degree level]
```

Parentheses are not not required in this case, but I don't see why they would have caused a problem in the first place.

I never use the same name for a table and one of its fields.  I'm not confident that is the source of the problem either, but I would alias the table name to see whether that change has any effect.

If this version of the query still doesn't work, rename the table to `tblDegree` and see whether even that can work.

Comment: I was just going to suggest the same thing about something being misspelled.